# po message file build

Tags: gettext, poedit, po, mo

Is it possible to build a `*.po` file to `*.mo` using the terminal?

Currently, I have to edit the `*.po` file in my text editor, save it, load it via **Poedit** and save it again.

I am working on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use msgfmt

Msgfmt /path/to.PO -o path/to/new.mo